# Methods for Custom Form Creation on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, permissions, custom-form

This could be a user error, but I am having issues creating a custom form in SharePoint Online (SPO).

This form is to be in a document library. I only have `Full Control` permissions to that library and nothing else. I am a bit unfamiliar with SPO and cannot find the tools I need to create a form.

I have SharePoint Designer 2013 installed on my computer, but cannot connect to SP site. I am currently working on that issue.

Though supposing SPD does not work/isn't authorized in the environment and my google-fu isn't as good anymore.

What resources and/or alternatives can I use for custom form creation?

A new guy at this place so I don't know who the site collections admin is. The only SP admin I've found works on a hosted SP farm and, unfortunately, has no interaction with the SP site I'm working on.

Any advice would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

The `Full control` on the library is not sufficient permission to be able to use SharePoint Designer to customize or create SharePoint forms.

**To be able to use SharePoint Designer**, you should be a member of **one** of the following groups at site collection level

- Site Owner.
- Designer.
- Site Collection Administrator.

For more details check

- [Manage Permissions and Control Access to Sharepoint Designer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2592376/manage-permissions-and-control-access-to-sharepoint-designer)
- [Site Owner vs Site Collection Administrator](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/site-owner-vs-site-collection-administrator)

---

**The available tools that you can use to create/customize SharePoint forms**

- SharePoint Designer.
- InfoPath.
- PowerApps.

You can also use 3rd party tools like K2, formotus, ...etc.

> **Note:** All the above tools will also require sufficient permissions as I mentioned above.

See also [SharePoint designer 2016 and InfoPath 2016, what’re the alternatives?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess I'm still in limbo permission-wise. Though I have another question, would MS Access be a resource as well or is that something I should leave alone (not database savvy)?

Comment: MS access can be a tool to connect and extract data from SharePoint lists, but not to submit

Comment: As Mike said, the Access can be used to create forms and reports from a SharePoint list as only **views**!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking a look at [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/sharepoint-forms/) for SharePoint Online. This tool allows you to design completely responsive forms with tabs, accordions, repeating rows and save them in SharePoint modern pages. You can configure automatic routing between different forms based on user's membership, field values, or any other data from SharePoint. Also, you can implement more complex logic e.g. conditional visibility, disabling fields based on others, populating fields conditionally with the help of its rich JS-framework.

It's not free but for now you have not so many options for designing forms for SharePoint Modern UI - Power Apps and Plumsail Forms.

Answer (score 0):

check what's blocking SPD from connecting to SharePoint
it could be that you don't have enable the modern authentication to be able to connect from SPD to SPO

Look at this steps to enable ADAL on Office 2013

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-Modern-Authentication-for-Office-2013-on-Windows-devices-7dc1c01a-090f-4971-9677-f1b192d6c910

The same for InfoPath Designer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly, I have no way to verify that setting. I also do not who is the site admin (as I'm sure that would help me a lot)....I've spent some time looking for that unicorn at my location.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the form in SharePoint Online with InfoPath or some client side script to do custom style,logic in the form.
some reference:

[How Can I Customize List Forms in SharePoint Online?](http://sympmarc.com/2016/11/11/how-can-i-customize-list-forms-in-sharepoint-online/)

Also PowerApps is also a good option:
[Customize a SharePoint list form using PowerApps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/customize-list-form)